# How can i create a folder in Amazon S3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Below is my code to upload document to S3 which works fine but can you help how can I create a folder in a bucket if it does not exist and upload the file into that folder

```
try
        {
            TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new
            TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1));

            // Specify advanced settings/options.
            TransferUtilityUploadRequest fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = existingBucketName,
                FilePath = filePath,
                StorageClass = S3StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy,
                PartSize = 9291456, // 6 MB.
                Key = keyName,
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
            };
            fileTransferUtility.UploadDirectory("C:\\Build", existingBucketName);
            fileTransferUtilityRequest.Metadata.Add("param1", "Value1");
            fileTransferUtilityRequest.Metadata.Add("param2", "Value2");
            fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
            Console.WriteLine("Upload 4 completed");

        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s3Exception.Message,
                              s3Exception.InnerException);
        }
```

Comment: IIRC, S3 doesn't understand the concept of folders; rather, it just has really long file names which can include slashes.  It is a flat file system.

Answer (score 4):

```cs
public void CreateFolder(string awsBucketName, string awsFolderName)
{
    EncryptionMaterials encryptionMaterials = new EncryptionMaterials(RSA.Create());

    AmazonS3EncryptionClient client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(encryptionMaterials);
        if ((cloudKaseClient != null) & (_Security.IsTokenAuthenticate(tokenUsr, tokenPasswd)))
        {
            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest
            {

                BucketName = awsBucketName,
                StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard,
                ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256,
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.Private,
                Key = awsFolderName + "/",
                ContentBody = awsFolderName
            };

            client.PutObject(putObjectRequest);

    }
}
```

For concept of Amazon S3 if you want differentiate file and folder than folder path get by path with "/"  and for File path get without "/".

Also if you want to create folder name with "/" than amazon s3 browser create that folder without "/".

For Creating File Use Below code

```
public void CreateFile(string awsBucketName, string awsFolderName)
{
    EncryptionMaterials encryptionMaterials = new EncryptionMaterials(RSA.Create());

    AmazonS3EncryptionClient client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(encryptionMaterials);
        if ((cloudKaseClient != null) & (_Security.IsTokenAuthenticate(tokenUsr, tokenPasswd)))
        {
            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest
            {

                BucketName = awsBucketName,
                StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard,
                ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256,
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.Private,
                Key = awsFolderName,
                ContentBody = awsFolderName
            };

            client.PutObject(putObjectRequest);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is important to know that there is no concept of Folders at Amazon S3. These are just long S3 File names with slashes within them, which are used to group [Amazon S3 Objects](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--what-is-object-introduction.html)..

By sending PUT Object request you can create a folder. In the request, you need to put "/" in its name, then strings separated by "/" and file size is zero.

For more details : [Amazon S3 - How to Create a Folder?](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-create-a-folder.html)